# Permutations of k types for a number smaller then total of k's (without replacement)

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

How can you find the number of permutations of a set of items grouped in different categories when you must choose less than the total of the set.

For example, I have a set of $12$ songs that are in $3$ groups ($3$ songs I like, $4$ I dislike, $5$ I am neutral). I play $4$ songs (without repeats), how many possible permutations of songs (according to my likes/dislikes/neutrals) are possible of those four songs played?

I can't use permutations of $k$ types ($\frac{n!}{k1!k2!}$) because I'm choosing less then the total of all the $k$'s.

A bit lost how to proceed, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly? Say what does it mean "according to my likes/dislikes/neutrals"?

Comment: Hi, no problem, sorry if it was confusing. I meant how many permutations of L(like), D(dislike), and N(neutral) are possible in the first 4 songs. For example, (LLLD, LLLN, LLDD, LLDN, LLNN, etc...).

Comment: Sorry to say that your example may not be good as we usually see different songs as not identical... And to the question, at least we can use inclusion exclusion principle, not know if there is some close formula